# Flutter: gradle issue

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

i have this problem when running my flutter app

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.



> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different 
version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.1.1) classpath. You 
should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution


* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or 
--debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full 
insights.


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

and i tried to solve it by adding

```
subprojects {
project.configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
       if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
               && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
           details.useVersion "26.1.0"
       }
   }
}
}
```

but it doesn't work

Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: did you try running flutter clean before?

Comment: yes i made it, flutter clean, flutter doctor, nothing

Answer (score 0):

Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has **different 
version** for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.1.1) classpath. So you have to update to be in the same version.